# Logging the time it takes to fill a LinkedList and Array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, linked-list, console-application

This Console-application is a bit strange but kinda funny, if it works. First, I'm clocking the time it takes to fill a `LinkedList` with **4.000.000 elements, with random numbers**. Then I'm searching for 100 random elements in that `LinkedList`. And between this I'm writing out the time it took to fill and find the elements.

After that I'm trying to do the same thing again, but with an `Array`. First filling it, then **looking for 100 random elements**. And then I'm sorting the `array`, to see the difference between looking for 100 random elements in a unsorted vs sorted `array`. And then typing the time again.

The problem is, after I've filled the `LinkedList`, and found the elements in the `LinkedList`, I'm starting to fill the Array with a loop. And I get a infinite loop. I really don't know what's wrong ATM.

I suggest, if you want to help, that you copy the code I'm pasting into this question, so you understand how it should look for all the parts of the program.

Code:

```
    public static bool sokning(int[] a, int b)
    {
        bool sant = false;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Stopwatch watchFindArray = new Stopwatch();
        Console.Write("Letar efter tal: ");
        watchFindArray.Start();
        int myint = 0;

        for (int iii = 0; iii < a.Length; iii++)
        {
            b = rand.Next();
            Console.Write("#");
            myint = Array.BinarySearch(a, b);

            if (myint < 0)
            {
                sant = false;
            }
            else
            {
                sant = true;
            }
        }
        watchFindArray.Stop();

        if (sant == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nFann alla element efter " + watchFindArray.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " sekunder.");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void körMetod()
    {
        const int MAX = 40000000;
        int[] array = new int[MAX];
        int hittamig2 = 0;
        Random rand2 = new Random();

        Stopwatch watchArray = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine("\nStartar Array...");
        watchArray.Start();
        Console.Write("Position: ");
        for (int ii = 0; ii < MAX; ii++)
        {
            array[ii] = rand2.Next();
            if (array.Length % 1000000 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }
        }
        watchArray.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\nTid: " + watchArray.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " sekunder att fylla en array.");
        Console.WriteLine("Letar efter tal: ");
        bool sant = sokning(array, hittamig2);


        Console.WriteLine("Sorterar arrayen.");
        Array.Sort(array);
        sant = sokning(array, hittamig2);

        if (sant == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nHittade inte alla element i arrayen.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Klar!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        const int MAX = 40000000;
        LinkedList<int> lankadLista = new LinkedList<int>();
        Stopwatch watchLinkedList = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine("Startar LinkedList...");
        watchLinkedList.Start();
        Console.Write("Position: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            lankadLista.AddLast(rnd.Next());
            if (lankadLista.Count() % 1000000 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }
        }
        watchLinkedList.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\nTid: " + watchLinkedList.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " sekunder att fylla en LinkedList.");
        Stopwatch watchFindLinkedList = new Stopwatch();
        int hittaMig;
        Console.Write("Letar efter tal: ");
        watchFindLinkedList.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            hittaMig = rnd.Next();
            Console.Write("#");
            lankadLista.Find(hittaMig);
        }
        watchFindLinkedList.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\nFann alla element efter " +
        watchFindLinkedList.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " sekunder.");

        Console.ReadLine();

        körMetod();
    }
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Did you try to debug it ands see why the loop condition state doesn't change?

Comment: Yes, i've tried to change the loop values. But the strange this is that i make the same loop for the LinkedList, and that works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not in an infinite loop, the problem is that it the following code:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < MAX; ii++)
{
    array[ii] = rand2.Next();
    if (array.Length % 1000000 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("#");
    }
}
```

The inner condition is `array.Length % 1000000 == 0` which is always `true` because the size of `array` is always **40000000** as you initialized it:

```
const int MAX = 40000000;
int[] array = new int[MAX];
```

When you are doing `array[ii] = rand2.Next();` you are not changing the length of the array you are just setting one of its cells with a value equals to `rand2.Next();`.

This causes the `Console.Write("#");` to work in **every iteration** and also slowing your loop dramatically.

To fix this, just change:

```
if (array.Length % 1000000 == 0)
```

to:

```
if (ii % 1000000 == 0)
```

*You* ***don't want*** *to add new item at the end of the array every time* because, resizing the array **reallocates the array every time which is super slow** but you can do it using the [`Array.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) method (no reason for you to do it)

Comment: With the LinkedList im using the method .AddLast. Is there something like that with arrays? Kinda stuck with ideas how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a big problem in the routine that searches the Array. (`sokning`)

Where is the code that searches for only 100 elements?

It seems that your are searching a random generated number for 40 millions times. Just fixing the Console.Write("#") to write correctly at every million point is not enough. I think that the big delay that let you think to have an infinite loop is in your code that search 40 millions of random generated numbers in an array of 40 millions of numbers

Of course this is not very "responsive" (considering also that you call this method two times)

```
public static bool sokning(int[] a, int b)
{
    bool sant = false;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Stopwatch watchFindArray = new Stopwatch();
    Console.Write("Letar efter tal: ");
    watchFindArray.Start();
    int myint = 0;

    // Search only 100 numbers like you do in the linked list
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 100; iii++)
    {
        b = rand.Next();
        Console.Write("#");
        myint = Array.BinarySearch(a, b);

        if (myint < 0)
        {
            sant = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sant = true;
        }
    }
    watchFindArray.Stop();

    if (sant == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nFann alla element efter " + watchFindArray.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " sekunder.");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There are also two minor problems.

Why passing the variable `b` inside the `sokning` method? The original value is never used and when you start the loop to search a random generated number the b variable os overwritten. So I think you could remove it

The second problem is the result of this `sokning` method. You set the `sant` variable to true or false at every loop. So the latest loop wins. In other words, if the latest loop finds a match you return true or false if not. If some previous loop has a different result, it is totally lost for the callers of `sokning`.